Probability both selected are female?
I'm given two categories, car owners or bike owners in a sample. $0.6$ people own cars, and of those $0.6$ who own cars, $0.5$ are female. Of those who own bikes, $0.3$ are female. If two individuals are randomly selected, what is the probability that both are female?
My process is that the total probability will be the sum of both car owners who are female, both bike owners who are female, and one female car owner and one female bike owner.
$$P(F) = (0.6 \times 0.5)^2 + (0.4 \times 0.3)^2 + (0.6 \times 0.5 \times 0.4 \times0.3)$$
Would this be a correct line of thinking? Apologies if I've understood this wrong. Edit: Assuming that car owners and bike owners do not overlap, and each individual falls into either car or bike category.

Do you pick both individual at the same time or one after another, so knowing who is the first ?

@EDX I believe it is at the same time

This is not clear.  First of all, how big is the sample?  Can we assume that it is so large that the selections can be treated as independent?  And, are we to assume that those who don't own cars do own bikes?  And are we to assume that nobody owns both a car and a bike?

We indeed need more precision !

@lulu, can you clarify why given only this information, why a large sample size should help towards the simplification that the selections are independent?

@lulu Sorry, I've made some edits to help clarify my question

@Srini  Well, work an example.  Say $.1$ percent of a sample is female.  If you have $10$ people, then it is impossible to choose two females.  If you have $100$ people, the probability of choosing two females is $\frac {10}{100}\times \frac 9{99}$ which is a lot closer to $.1^2$ which would be the "independent" calculation.

I don't see how the edits answer my questions.   The population size is critical.

Thanks @lulu, makes sense

If you assume an arbitrarily large population then you need to double the cross terms, as you might first choose the car driving woman and then the bike driving woman, or the opposite order.

@lulu I understand your example, so without an explicit n I'm not able to compute this problem? Or if it was assumed to very large, how would I go about this?

As I said in my last comment, if the population is so large that you can treat the selections as if they were independent, then your method is almost right, you just need to double the third term.

Assuming a large population, there is an easier way to think about it. 0.6x0.5+.4x0.3= 42% of the population is female. So probability of 2 females is $0.42^2$.

$~(a + b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + ~\color{red}{2}ab.~$  So, $${ ~[0.6 \times 0.5] + [0.4 \times 0.3] ~}^2 $$ $$= [0.6 \times 0.5]^2 +  [0.4 \times 0.3]^2 ~+ \color{red}{2} ~{ ~[0.6 \times 0.5] \times [0.4 \times 0.3] ~}.$$
